# How to programmatically open ngbootstrap popover for a d3 element?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, d3.js, ng-bootstrap

I want to open a popover onmouseover for a D3 element.

Essentially this means my component.html file is almost empty, containing only the popover template:

`<ng-template #popContent let-greeting="greeting">{{greeting}}, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>`

I can't use the usual

`[ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Greeting" #p="ngbPopover" triggers="manual"`

attributes, since target D3 element doesn't exist yet

**What I need is to be able to somehow call the popover's open function passing the popover contents and position.**
something like this in my component:

```
public showPopover(node, text){ // node is the DOM element for which to show popover
 ... what should go here? ...
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) has an example of manually triggering the popover (scroll to **Context and manual triggers**).

Comment: @Mark but it doesn't say how to attach it to an arbitrary dom element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like the API provides a way to create the popover on [dynamic elements](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api) (see container).  Since angular wants you to avoid direct access on the DOM, you have to create the popup via a template.  So, I'd create it on a "blank" element and then move it to your dynamic element.  That said, once you move it you'll have to trigger it manually since *events* will all be on the "blank" element.  Something like this:

**Template**

```
<!-- empty span to create the popover on -->
<!-- note the "manual" trigger -->
<span ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on top"
        #popover="ngbPopover" triggers="manual">
</span>

<div #base></div> <!-- where my dynamic element will go -->
```

**Controller**

```
import {NgbPopover} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Component, ViewChild, ngAfterViewInit, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-tplwithcontext',
  templateUrl: 'src/popover-tplwithcontext.html'
})

export class NgbdPopoverTplwithcontext implements ngAfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('popover') public popover: NgbPopover;
  @ViewChild('base') el:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){

    // create dynamic element
    let s = d3.select(this.el.nativeElement)
      .append('button')
      .html('Dynamically Added!')
      // manual open
      .on('click', () => { this.openPop(); })

    // assign popover our new element
    this.popover._elementRef = new ElementRef(s.node());
  }

  // handle the opening/closing
  public openPop(): void {
    console.log(this)
    this.popover.isOpen() ? this.popover.close() : this.popover.open();
  }
}
```

Here is a [running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9h3ztByDp8VnIuZqFSLc?p=preview).

Comment: Alternative would be to create an instance of an NgbPopover in your component. It has a long list of dependencies which you'd have to inject into your component for the sole reason of passing to NgbPopover though. This hack is a more maintainable solution in my opinion!

Comment: In ngbootstrap version 9.0.2, it says [Property '_elementRef' is private and only accessible within class 'NgbPopover'"]

Answer (score 1):

Hi it was useful thank you, but I have to add a thing you need to change the property ".elementRef" to public in the definition file popover.d.ts

```
export declare class NgbPopover implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
public _elementRef;
```